# Lie group not related to matrix group

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Does there exist a Lie group that doesn’t come from a matrix group? Of course covers or quotients of matrix groups might not be matrix groups, and you can always take products of things like these to get more non-matrix groups. But is there a non-matrix Lie group that cannot be obtained from matrix groups using these operations?

Answer (score 2):

Ado theorem says that every Lie algebra ${\cal G}$ can be embedded to a matrix Lie algeba. This induces a covering map between the simply connected group whose Lie algebra is ${\cal G}$ and a matrix group therefore  the quotient of the universal cover  of  a connected Lie group is a matrix group.

Comment: Very important point - every **finite dimensional** Lie algebra.